# Use same binder multiple times in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am writing a small php program and I am new to PDO.
There is a live search component in my program. 
 
User's query should search with two table columns.
I know how to write the query in traditional mysql.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM items WHERE (i_name LIKE ='%$query%') OR (i_code LIKE '%$query%')';
```

But I don't know how to do the same in `mysqli`. 
When I run the following code, it will show the following error.

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in
```

Following is my code.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['term'])){
     // Prepare a select statement
     $sql = 'SELECT * FROM items WHERE (i_name LIKE ?) OR (i_code LIKE ?)';

     if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($ds, $sql)){
         // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);

         // Set parameters
         $param_term = $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';

         // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
         if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
             $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

             // Check number of rows in the result set
             if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                 // Fetch result rows as an associative array
                echo '<table class="table table-striped"><tbody><tr>';
                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

                    echo '<td width="70%">' . $row["i_name"] . '</td><td width="30%"><a href="edit-cat.php?cat='.$row['iid'].'"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</a></td>';
                 }
                echo '</tr></tbody></table>';
             } else{
                 echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
             }
         } else{
             echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($ds);
         }
     }

     // Close statement
     mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
 }

 // close connection
 mysqli_close($ds);
 ?>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
function selectCountry(val) {
$("#search-box").val(val);
$("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
            $.get("search-item.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                resultDropdown.html(data);
            });

        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have two placeholders in the query, you need to use two variables in `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`. You can use the same variable both times to bind multiple placeholders.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_term, $param_term);
```

Comment: Then there's probably nothing matching the search term. What does `var_dump($term);` show? What rows in the database do you expect it to match?

Comment: There are several matches. 
Earlier, if I use only one condition in the query, it successfully printed db values.
I need to match 'i_name' and 'i_code' columns

Comment: If it matches either column by itself, using `OR` can't return fewer matches.

Comment: This is the query for single column search

   ` if(isset($_REQUEST['term'])){
     // Prepare a select statement
     $sql = 'SELECT * FROM items WHERE (i_name LIKE ?) ';
//OR (i_code LIKE ?)
     if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($ds, $sql)){
         // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);

         // Set parameters
         $param_term = $_REQUEST['term'] . '%'; `

Comment: Don't paste code in comments, add it to the question.

Comment: @Barmar I think the Op might be missing the wildcards

Comment: @Strawberry He has `$param_term = $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';` which has the wildcard at the end.

Comment: @JehanFernando In your original code you have `%$query%` which has the wildcards on both sides of the search string. In your new code you only have the wildcard at the end, so the search term has to match at the beginning. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Barmar No I want to search in multiple column with same '?'

Comment: There's no reason it shouldn't work then. I asked you to post sample data and the value of `$param_term`.

Comment: @Barmar G45, G49

Comment: @Barmar what do you think about $sql ? Is it correct?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: I'll ask one more time, then I give up on you. Edit your question to show sample table contents and the output of `var_dump($param_term)`.